# Difference between basic and Visual Studio professional subscription access levels in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Could someone throw some light on the difference between basic and Visual Studio professional subscription access levels in Azure DevOps?

Microsoft document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops) provides abstract information regarding the different access levels.

We have few users who are tagged with basic access level (who also have Visual Studio Professional Subscription) while few other users with Visual Studio professional subscription.

It is understood from this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/) that basic access level subscription billed $6 per month, the question that arises now is if azure devops is available for usage without cost if the user has visual studio professional subscription, and do we need to buy basic access level for users who do not have Visual studio professional subscription.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer help you clearly the difference between basic and visual Studio subscriber? Don’t hesitate to let us know your puzzle:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The difference between basic and Visual Studio professional
>   subscription access levels in Azure DevOps?

First, assume this professional subscription is available, not expired.

For active and valid subscription, it has all features of **Basic**. And also, as a VS Subscriber, you will have a **basic license** which included in VS subscription. Meanwhile, you can also [use a range of features in Azure DevOps that are included with your subscription as a benefit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/vs-azure-devops).

For example, the subscribers have Basic + Test Plans included with their subscription. But for basic user, their Test Plan need be purchased additionally.

But, if the user don't have valid subscription or expired, at this time, this user will work as Stackholder.

> Do we need to buy basic access level for users who do not have Visual
>   studio professional subscription.

As I mentioned previously, the Basic feature is included in the Visual Studio Professional Subscription. So, about these users, you don't need worry about their permission, just pay attention for not expired.

But, for the users who do not have the Visual Studio Professional Subscription, you only have 5 free Basic feature. If these free quotas are used up. You must buy the Basic for them.

**Update:**

You can see that in the Users tab, and also can get clearly know that who has subscriber level, who just has Basic level and who own Basic + Test Plan:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, So I could summarise the following based on your answer. Users having valid VS Prof subscription can access Azure DevOps with Basic access level. In case Test plans are needed then the additional purchase is required.

Comment: So how do I differentiate between the VS subscription users and those users where the purchase was made for basic access level.

Comment: Yeah, but purchase Test Plan is only for anyone who only has Basic level. Because for VS subscriber, the Basic level + Test Plan are all has, if it does not expired.

Comment: In the Users page of org setting, you will see its deffience. I will updated with a pic in my answer to let you clear about it.

Comment: @Santhosh, Did you still have any puzzle about the VS subscriber and basic level?

Comment: These answers clarify most of the things, Thank you.

Comment: Hi Again, We have a new user added to azure devops with VS professional, but the access rights for the user is stakeholder. Can you help us in this case?

Comment: @Santhosh Whether this license is expired? Only the expired license has the same access level with stackholder. In addition, does this user ever try sign out and sign in again? Sometimes this method only used when the server does not analysis the license automatically while first login with license.

Comment: This is not an expired license, but a new VS professional subscription.

Comment: The user is not able to view the organisation.

Comment: @Santhosh Not able to view? Do you mean that this user has the 401 error while login to the org? Only this user who has the professional license could not view? What about the other user who also has this professional license?

Comment: It works for other users, only for the new user with a new VS professional subscription is not able to view the organization.

Comment: @Santhosh Does this “not able to view “ means 401 unauthorized error or same with stackholder level? What about try with browser of incognito mode and sign out / sign in again?

Comment: It's not 401 error. Let me try sign out and sign in using incognito mode.

Comment: @Santhosh It’s access level similiar with stackholder? Waiting your result:-) (Another details confirm: did you assign the professional license to this user?)

Comment: @Santhosh How the things going? Does this user can access the org successfully now? If still not, since Stack Overflow is a open forum, it's not security to share your  org name and user account to let me help you check from backend. I recommend you raise the ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21).

Comment: In that question content, just **share this stack overflow link**, then describe your issue and error. After create the ticket, **share your org and user account in comment with choosing Microsoft Only** to protect your info. My colleague will help you check why from our backend. In addition, if you don't mind, you can also share that Developer Community ticket link to me. So that I can contact my colleague who receiving your ticket to describe your details and help you track.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198649/discussion-between-santhosh-and-merlin-liang-msft).